# How to get nested attribute and images from Json response

Tags: java, json, gson

I receive from server a response in this form

```
{"error":null,"id":1,"result":
{"admin":false,
"firstname":"Jason",
"id":346,"idHotel":109,
"idVendor":null,
"lastname":"Butcher",
"sessionkey":"3c8a17ae47a6d131b1a14b44a1d8f9a9",
"urlAvatar":"avatar_316_mjm.jpg",
"urlThumb":"thumb_316_mjm.jpg"}
}
```

And want to get the various singles attributes,

for example

```
Boolean error=..;
String admin=....;
String idHotel=...;
```

and also the images

Comment: hey, I see this response as the most simple one, I think you need to read about JSON formating and JSON parsing in android first to get sure about how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a wrapper class like this:

```
public class Response {
    public boolean error;
    public int id;
    public Result result;
}

public class Result {
    ...
}
```

then is simple for you to deserialize the json via gson to you classes:

```
Response response = new Response();
Gson gson = new Gson();
response = gson.fromJson(response, Response.class);
```

And there's a lot of other nifty things you can do: https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide

Oh forgot one important thing! 
Remember to change the namespace on the Gson library, I had problems get it running on htc telephones. You can do this with jar jar links: http://code.google.com/p/jarjar/downloads/list

docs: http://code.google.com/p/jarjar/wiki/CommandLineDocs

Comment: thank you for the answer. could you give me more details about the namespace matter??

Comment: Yes of cause, My app couldn't run on some htc telephons. So I found the following issue report:http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/issues/detail?id=255 Where the solution is described in comment 9.

Comment: I have tried with this sintax but with no success... how exactly I should pass the server response in the second code-block?

Comment: if I try to use this sintax says that I must change in .toJson, but I want to extract the various nested data from an existing Json

Comment: Sorry to comment so late.. Did you get it working or should I be more explicit in my example?

Comment: I have tried another solution however If you can give more details this example could be more usefull. thanks